# How to get div content with innerHTML as plain text and then download it as txt file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, innerhtml

What I'm trying to do is basically create a plugin to generate the innerHTML of a div content called main and download it as a text file. However I don't want to get the post-rendered html after it runs all the js/jquery functions. I managed to do this however the problem is that it generates everything.

HTML:

```
<button id= "clickhere">CLICK HERE</button>
<div id="main">
    <p id="yeah" class="hide">asdasdadadad</p>

    <span>Hey there</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#clickhere').click(function(){
    //location.reload();
    downloadeverything();
});


function downloadeverything(){

function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {

    var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click(); 
}

var fileName =  'testing.txt';
downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'main','text/html');
}

    $('#yeah').show('puff', 750);
```

Obviously my project is bigger but I created a sample fiddle to show the problem. Basically when I add the fadeIn or puff Jquery animation the txt file generated gives me a style: display:block on the txt file as shown in the picture.
[image]

I found a non-ideal workaround which is to add the download function on the top so it runs first but then again that's not what I want as it doesn't work when I have more than 1 js file running.

I've also tried to force reload and immediately download but it doesn't work. Is there a way of pre-rendering the html file as txt so i can get the text i want or setting the html content to string when i click the download button?

My sample: http://jsfiddle.net/yomuffin89/fzg39sk5/8/

**Update:** I need to include script tags with animation within the main div(i know .. but its ie6) so if the code generates in sequence then it gets everything within that div. is there a way to run the file as txt so it gets just that div content as text without anything applied to it afterwords?

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yomuffin89/fzg39sk5/13/

If anyone can help I would be grateful.

Comment: Have a look at this [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fzg39sk5/9/). Use `.text()` instead of `.innerHTML`

Comment: the problem with this though is that it doesn't get the tags. I don't need just the text. I also need to include p, div, ul tags etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get your content onPageLoad event like this:

```
var elHtml;

$('#clickhere').click(function(){
location.reload();
downloadeverything();

});


function downloadeverything(){

function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
    link.click(); 
}

var fileName =  'testing.txt';
downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'main','text/html');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
elHtml = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML;
$('#yeah').show('puff', 750);
});
```

Comment: this works but i forgot to mention in my description that I also want it to get the script tags as well within the html.. i haven't provided that in fiddle but you get the idea. do you know if it's possible?

Comment: Is your script tags within the <body></body> tags?

Comment: yes.. i know its not ideal but i have to use an old softwear to support ie6. that's why im trying to do that plugin to make life easier.

Comment: Try getting the innerHTML of the <body></body> tags it should grab the script tags as well...

Comment: I tried but because i'm using a softwear to publish this, if the script is not included within the body, it won't work after i publish. is there a way to get the div content as string?

Comment: div content as string or script content as string?

Comment: both as the script is within that div. i know its really bad practice but again its not up to me. can i get everything as string so it doesn't run as html when i download it as txt file?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "so it doesn't run as html"...You could get innerHTML of div tag that should give you div and script.  If you want to create txt file without displaying anything you could create a different page that downloads this page as text/plain then create a txt file for this page from another page?

Comment: Managed finally to do it. I had an issue with other js files which took me hours but your solution is working! when i load the animation on doc ready it works!!! massive thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the initial contents of the target div(s) and save them in a data attribute of the same div. Then upon click, you can retrieve the contents from there:

```
$('#main').each(function() {
    $(this).data('contents', $(this).html());
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/fzg39sk5/10/)

Comment: this again works however i have script within html. i dont want to have to run everything in sequence in order to get what i want. is there a way to run the file as txt instead of html and export as txt the div content i want? http://jsfiddle.net/yomuffin89/fzg39sk5/12/ - latest